# Constantly update csv file while writing to it (Windows)

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I have a situation with csv files on Windows. Every time I want to append some info to it, I need to kill process before the data could be appended to a file. Is there a way to append data to a file without closing the program every time I want to do so?
By the way, here is the code (I am using tkinter window to give the ninth value to a row):

```
def process_emg(emg, times):
    name = v.get()
    with open('own_test.csv', 'a+', newline='') as file:
        writing = csv.writer(file)
        writing.writerow(emg+(name,))
```

Comment: It depends on the other program that has the file open. Windows generally requires cooperative sharing for read, write, and delete/rename operations on files. Many programs keep a file open without sharing write and delete access. Python opens files using Microsoft's C runtime, which shares read and write access, but not delete/rename access.